# DLL load failed while importing cv2 Not enough memory resources are available to process this command

Tags: python, tensorflow, opencv, tensorflow2.0

My Input

```
python model_main_tf2.py --model_dir=models\my_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite --pipeline_config_path=models\my_ssd_mobilenet_v2_fpnlite\pipeline.config
```

Output

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "model_main_tf2.py", line 32, in <module>
    from object_detection import model_lib_v2
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\model_lib_v2.py", line 29, in <module>
    from object_detection import eval_util
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\eval_util.py", line 36, in <module>
    from object_detection.metrics import lvis_evaluation
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\object_detection\metrics\lvis_evaluation.py", line 23, in <module>
    from lvis import results as lvis_results
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\lvis\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from lvis.vis import LVISVis
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\lvis\vis.py", line 1, in <module>
    import cv2
  File "D:\Users\Ozgur\anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\lib\site-packages\cv2\__init__.py", line 5, in <module>
    from .cv2 import *
ImportError: DLL load failed while importing cv2: Not enough memory resources are available to process this command.
```

I try pip install opencv-python and other And I research but ı not found this error There is 20 gb of free space on the computer My reference https://github.com/armaanpriyadarshan/Training-a-Custom-TensorFlow-2.x-Object-Detector Please Help me.

Comment: "Memory resources" here means RAM space. How much space does your ram have? 8gb?

Comment: I Have a 8gb ram

Comment: That's why it can't load the model into ram. I suggest you use Google Colab which will provide you 12 gb ram and at least 16 gb gpu

Comment: My laptop has 16gb of ram. The video card is gtx 1060. Do you think I should do this from leptob?

Comment: I think you should try.

Comment: Thanks, I'll report the result

Comment: Everything went very well but in this part it stopped and didn't move.Use fn_output_signature instead .; https://prnt.sc/104ecjv

Comment: Then you have to read Tensorflow documentation to update the code by yourself. It's better to ask someone else other than posting more problems in one question

Answer (score 2):

I was having the same issue while training a model using tensorflow object detection API for custom dataset.
I struggled a lot in starting but in end i did

```
conda update -c conda-forge --all
```

I don't know why but it worked for me.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).