# Python: Why does a DLL memory error occur when just importing CV2 on gpu-enabled interpreter?

Tags: python, opencv, anaconda, conda

I have searched far and wide but cannot find a solution to this problem. I am currently running a GPU enabled interpreter (Python v3.8) using CUDA/CUDNN on Pycharm. I am simply trying to import cv2 (v4.5.3.56) and I am getting one constant error:

> DLL load failed while importing cv2: Not enough memory resources are
> available to process this command.

Apparently the error happens in cv2/**init**.py folder on this line:

```
from .cv2 import *
```

I am guessing the problem is this DLL file here as it is the only one in the cv2 library directory: `opencv_videoio_ffmpeg453_64.dll`

I have tried updating my PATH variables, dragging a python3.dll file into Anaconda, conda/pip install all kinds of opencv/cv2 version. None of this works. I see one other questions similar to this one but no answer. Also, I should note that all I am doing is importing the library. Nothing else.

[DLL load failed while importing cv2 Not enough memory resources are available to process this command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66315487/dll-load-failed-while-importing-cv2-not-enough-memory-resources-are-available-to) both have this issue.

Comment: Please link the two other questions. Have you tried profiling memory usage? How much memory is available to the interpreter?

Comment: Updated post to include two other stack questions, thanks. As for memory on the interpreter, all I am doing is importing CV2 on an empty python file. It should have plenty of memory in theory. Task Manager doesn't seem to show me using too much ram on my machine.